# spring boot 2 + spring data jpa rollback transactions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, rollback

I have a spring boot 2 project with spring data jpa for persistence.
I have a manager with a method that inside calls 3 different save method. each save is located in a service annotated as transactional at class level. Also the manager's method is annotated as transactional.
The db is PastgeSQL

the manager's method is

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void saveUserComplete(CustomUserDetail user, UserAnag anag, List<UserRolePermission> rolePermissions) {

        this.userDetailsService.save(user);

        this.userAnagService.save(anag);

        this.userRolePermissionService.saveAll(rolePermissions);

}
```

while the 3 service method called inside are

```
    public void save(CustomUserDetail user) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = c.getTime();
    UserEntity entity = null;
    if(null != user.getId()){
        Optional<UserEntity> entityOpt = this.userRepository.findById(user.getId());
        if(entityOpt.isPresent()){
            entity = entityOpt.get();
            entity.setUpdatedAt(now);
            //entity.setUpdateUser();
        }
    }
    else{
        entity = new UserEntity();
        entity.setCreatedAt(now);
        //entity.setCreatUser();
    }
    entity.fillEntityFromPojo(user);

    if(null != entity) { this.userRepository.save(entity); }
}
```

the first nethod called

```
public void save(UserAnag userAnag){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = c.getTime();
    UserAnagEntity entity = null;
    if (null != userAnag.getUsername()) {
        Optional<UserAnagEntity> entityOpt = this.userAnagRepository.findByUsername(userAnag.getUsername());
        if (entityOpt.isPresent()) {
            entity = entityOpt.get();
            entity.setUpdatedAt(now);
            //entity.setUpdateUser();
        } else {
            entity = new UserAnagEntity();
            entity.setCreatedAt(now);
            //entity.setCreatUser();
        }
        entity.fillEntityFromPojo(userAnag);
    }

    if (null != entity) {
        this.userAnagRepository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

the second method called

```
   public void saveAll(List<UserRolePermission> authorities) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = c.getTime();
    List<UserRolePermissionEntity> entities = Lists.newArrayListWithExpectedSize(authorities.size());

    for (UserRolePermission urp : authorities) {
        UserRolePermissionEntity entity = null;
        if (null != urp.getUsername()) {
            Optional<UserRolePermissionEntity> entityOpt = this.userRolePermissionRepository.findByUsernameAndRolenameAndPermission(urp.getUsername(), urp.getRolename(), urp.getPermission());
            if (entityOpt.isPresent()) {
                entity = entityOpt.get();
                entity.fillEntityFromPojo(urp);
                entity.setUpdatedAt(now);
                // entity.setUpdateUser();
            } else {
                entity = new UserRolePermissionEntity();
                entity.fillEntityFromPojo(urp);
                entity.setCreatedAt(now);
                // entity.setCreatUser();
            }
            entities.add(entity);
        }
    }

    if (!entities.isEmpty()) {
        String username = entities.get(0).getUsername();
        this.userRolePermissionRepository.deleteByUsername(username);
        this.userRolePermissionRepository.flush();
        this.userRolePermissionRepository.saveAll(entities);
    }
}
```

the last one.

What i expect is that if one of the save method fails the others are rollbacked, but now if one  fails the others are performed the same so i have only partial data saved on the db.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Let me guess as a db you are using MySQL and the table type you are using is MyISAM?

Comment: the db is potgresql ... i just updated my question

Comment: How is the call to `saveUserComplete()` done ? Is the method `saveUserComplete()` called from another method within the same class ? Could you please share the entire `Manager` class code ?

Comment: @R.G the manager contains only that method, and it'is called in a rest controller

Comment: Are you handling excepiion at repository or any layer before service ?  Other than that all looks good.

Comment: @R.G no, i'm not handling exception at repository, but i think they are managed by spring because they are not thrown

Comment: Unable to identify the issue from the code shared. The txn should rollback if the repository was autowired to manager class and there was a RuntimeException during the db calls. If possible please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share for us to debug